# Export rds query to s3 give error after some time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am trying to export data from a table in my postgresql database to S3. When I execute the query everything goes well, the data is exported correctly to S3, until suddenly after about 16 hours, the query gives an error:

```
ERROR: could not upload to Amazon S3
DETAIL: Amazon S3 client returned 'Unable to parse ExceptionName: ExpiredToken Message: The provided token has expired.'.
CONTEXT: SQL function "query_export_to_s3" statement 1
```

What could be the problem? I thought that the token was renewed 5 minutes before its expiration.

UPDATE: The role we use to execute the query has a session duration of 12h

More updates: The query I am running is to migrate several GB of data to S3, probably around 500 GB. I made a separate query to verify the number of records and the total is 500 million, this query took 4 hours to complete. Now what I did was run a query to export those 500 million records to S3 and after about 16 hours I get the message you see above.

In S3 the result was saved in parts of 6 GB.

We repeat the query that exports to S3 about 3 times and always the same result, after about 16 hours I get the expired token error.

I'm running the query from ec2 instance.

Comment: Is this a single select that times out after 16 hours, or is a series of selects? If the latter, how long has the specific query been running?

Comment: Can you point us to reference that says "the token is renewed 5 minutes before its expiration"?

Comment: Given the observed behavior, I think you'll have to break the operation into stages. Write all of the rows to a temporary table in RDS first, then export that table to S3. Perhaps in pieces.

Comment: @kdgregory Yeah, In fact that's what I did, I just wanted to know why this was happening, if maybe I was doing something wrong. Thank you for answering, if you answer the question, I will accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: This is all speculation on my part, so not an answer. While it's true that some (perhaps all) of the AWS SDKs have the ability to auto-renew an assumed role, there's no guarantee that this is being done with the RDS/S3 extension. It's possible that this extension gets credentials at the start of the export, assuming that it won't take that long .

Comment: And in most cases it shouldn't, but you appear to be exporting the results of a complex query, which means that the rows become available to be written over an extended time. It's possible that the extension _does_ retrieve new credentials for each PUT to S3, but that the time the query takes to generate rows means that those credentials have expired by the time the actual request is written (even though the role might have a 12 hour maximum duration, that might _not_ be the time requested when assuming the role).

Answer (score 0):

Please check AWS authentication [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtosessionduration.html#:%7E:text=The%20minimum%20session%20duration%20is%201%20hour%2C%20and%20can%20be%20set%20to%20a%20maximum%20of%2012%20hours.):

`The minimum session duration is 1 hour, and can be set to a maximum of 12 hours.`

Comment: Yes, we put the session in 12 hours and the result is the same.

Comment: Ok, but in your first message, you say that the process duration was 16 hours. Am I correct?

Comment: I made more updates